# Connect to facebook throw xmpp with non digid jid

Tags: facebook, xmpp

I need to code xmpp bot, which connects to facebook. I need to connect to facebook through xmpp. In old accounts the jid consist of sequence of digits.

Can I connect the way it connects in their official site, using given email or telephone number, instead of this sequence of number?

If someone have any information, can you help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in order to connect to facebook chat you need to use login like
my.name@chat.facebook.com
or
-1234567@chat.facebook.com

Info:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/